# Show calendar events with calendar-bundle adesigns

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fullcalendar, bundle

I am using the calendar fullcalendar.io that uses this bundle as explained in this link: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

It shows without problem, the inconvenience is when loading the events from the database. https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle#adding-events They are not loaded and do not show me any errors.

The code I am using is:

```
//app/config/service.yml
app_bundle.service.listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
    tags:
       - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'calendar.load_data', method: loadData }
```

Then in the class that would load the data from the database the following:

```
//AppBundle/EventListener/CalendarEventListener.php 
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
use BackendBundle\Entity\Torneos;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CalendarEventListener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }


    public function loadData(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
    {
        // You can retrieve information from the event dispatcher (eg, You may want which day was selected in the calendar):
        // $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStart();
        // $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEnd();
        // $filters = $calendarEvent->getFilters();

        // You may want do a custom query to populate the events
        // $currentEvents = $repository->findByStartDate($startDate);
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('BackendBundle:Torneos');
        $torneos = $repository->findAll();

        // You may want to add an Event into the Calendar view.
        /** @var Torneos $torneo */
        foreach ($torneos as $torneo) {
            $calendarEvent->addEvent(new Event($torneo->getNombre(), $torneo->getFechaInicio()));
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this does not load the information, which can be performed to make it work? what is missing

Regards

Comment: did you debug it? is `$torneos = $repository->findAll();` actually returns anything?

Comment: in this part of the code no but I use the same code in another place and it works I return all the records. In addition to being in the bundle I do not know how to make a debug

Comment: install [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install) or do `$torneos = $repository->findAll(); dump($torneos); die();`, what it shows you?

Comment: There is nothing that does not enter the class. Where is the error? Maybe the error is in this line: - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'calendar.load_data', method: loadData }

Comment: how do you dispatch the `calendar.load_data` event?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that's what's missing

Comment: You probably missing event dispatching, do `$this->dispatcher->dispatch('calendar.load_data', new CalendarEvent( /* arguments */ );` somewhere in the code, controller maybe, don't forget to initialize dispatcher

Comment: Reviewing in the documentation in the service invokes the method

Comment: yeah, but the service invokes the method on particular event (`calendar.load_data` in this case) and that event needs to be dispatched first

Comment: After reading the documentation indicates that in this line name: 'kernel.event_listener' is called the listener here asks to execute the code. Explication: https://diego.com.es/event-listeners-y-subscribers-en-symfony

Comment: $ php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher

Registered Listeners Grouped by Event
=====================================

"calendar.load_data" event
--------------------------

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
-
  Order   Callable                                                      Priority

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
-
  #1      AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener::onloadData()   0